# CSS Cut text overflow in label with display-type table

Tags: html, css

We are working on a webpage with HTML5 and CSS.

Each of our labels has a defined length in pixel and sometimes we got labels which have a content which is longer as the label.

So we want that the content is cut by a style like overflow:hidden per example.
Meanwhile we have found out, that it works if the label has the display-types block or inline-block, but this doesn't match for us because we need display-type "table".

But when we use "table" like in the following example, the label is enlarged, so it fits to the content.
With display.inline-block it would work.

Is there a way to make it work with "display:table" too?

```
<label id="40369" style="display: table; width: 260px; font-size: 14px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip;">This really a very very long text which will be much much longer as this label</label>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the solution!
It works when we add to the style

- white-space: nowrap;
- table-layout: fixed;

Here the complete example for comparing with the example from the question:

```
<label id="40369" style="display: table; width: 260px; font-size: 14px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: clip; white-space: nowrap; table-layout: fixed;">This really a very very long text which will be much much longer as this label</label>
```

Comment: why use display table at all for this?  I see no point in turning a label into a table, especially as it has no children that are of row or cell.  It just seems wrong to put text directly into something that is display table - after all you wouldn't put anything like that directly into a table tag